# Pagination Missing From Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1

I am currently using the freego magento 2 theme. My category pages do not display the pagination in the toolbar. I have triple checked settings, tried using the blank theme and the luma theme as well but it is still not displaying the pagination. What am I missing. I am new to magento. I found the toolbar code in the `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list` folder. I see `<?php echo $block->getPagerHtml() ?>` there.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Solwin_SoldOut module. This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solwin team updated the theme so please download latest FreeGo theme and use latest copy in your project.

Now you no need to disable any module for displaying pagination on categroy page.